# Django mutable POST doesn't appear in cleaned_data

Tags: django, forms, immutability, mutable

I have been searching around for this for two days now, but I couldn't find any realiable solution.

**form**:

```
class SMSSettingsForm(forms.ModelForm):
    smsQuota = forms.IntegerField(label=_("Account Quota"), max_value=432000, min_value=1, required=True, help_text=_('(mins)'), error_messages={'required': _('This field cannot be empty')})
    smsTimeout = forms.IntegerField(label=_("Timeout"), max_value=9999999, min_value=1,required=False, help_text=_("(mins)"))
    class Meta:
        model = Settings
        fields = ("smsQuota", "smsTimeout")

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(SMSSettingsForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def save(self):
        settings = SettingsManager.get()
        settings.smsQuota = self.cleaned_data['smsQuota']
        settings.smsTimeout = self.cleaned_data['smsTimeout']

        # Following lines are extra fields, rendered by JS in HTML
        settings.ck = self.cleaned_data['ck']
        settings.ck_per = self.cleand_data['ck_per']

        settings.save()
```

**view**:

```
form_with_extra_elem = request.POST.copy()
form_with_extra_elem['ck'] = request.POST.get("ck")
form_with_extra_elem['ck_per'] = request.POST.get("ck_per")
# The two lines above didn't work, so I tried the following, but didn't work again
#form_with_extra_elem.update({'ck': request.POST.get("ck")})
#form_with_extra_elem.update({'ckper': request.POST.get("ck_per")})
form = SMSSettingsForm(form_with_extra_elem)
```

Do you have any idea how to solve this? What I think is the new element doesn't pass by the `validation`, so I cannot use them. But how to make them to do so? Actually, I don't need any validation - is there any other way than `cleaned_data`, to access form parameters?

Comment: I think, if `ck` and `ck_per` are not part of `SMSSettingsForm` they will be ignored and will not be part of that form.

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand why you want to add extra fields via JS only. If you want them to appear in `cleaned_data`, they have to be part of the form. You can declare extra fields on a ModelForm simply by specifying them like you have with the other fields:

```
class SMSSettingsForm(forms.ModelForm):
    smsQuota = forms.IntegerField(...)
    smsTimeout = forms.IntegerField(...)
    ck_per = forms.IntegerField()
    ck = forms.IntegerField()
```